# merge watermark in OpenTBS/TinyButStrong

Tags: php, docx, watermark, opentbs, tinybutstrong

I am successfully using OpenTBS to merge data in MS-Word files.

How can I conditionally display a watermark in OpenTBS?

Using the `[TBS tag]` syntax in the watermark text does not work.

Answer (score 0):

In Ms Word, a watermark is made by the software by adding a picture or a WordArt feature into the header of the page.

So you can reach the watermark object simply by editing the header (double-click in the top of the page) an select the watermark text or picture.

Since you have reached the object, you can add a TBS field with conditional display parameters. For example, you can add it in the Alternative Text property at the Properties dialogue-box.

Example of a condiational TBS field that will delete the WordArt object when its value is equal to `1`:

```
[onload.delete;magnet=w:pict;ope=mko:1]
```

Note that whether the watermark is made by a WortArt or picture, the XLM of the corresponding object is `<w:pict>`.

Don't forget that a Ms Word document may have 3 headers: one for the first page, one for even pages and one for other pages.
See command OPENTBS_SELECT_HEADER at the [documentation](https://www.tinybutstrong.com/opentbs.php?doc#commands_for_documents).

Comment: I did not realize that watermarks are part of headers. Thanks for the clarification. Unfortunately the implementation I am working on does not allow to modify headers since a further step outside TBS adds custom headers (stationery) replacing whatever header is already present.

Comment: You could delete the `<w:pict>` element at the PHP side using the OpenTBS command `OPENTBS_DELETE_ELEMENTS`.